# Qt5: How to save XML so that elements are in a specific order?

Tags: xml, xsd, qt5

I have an XSD schema (not by me) that specifies a certain order for some XML elements. The problem is that when I read, modify and save an XML as a QDomDocument the order of elements can be anything even if hash randomization is disabled. How could I force a certain order so that the XML remain valid?

Comment: Could you give a minimal example? Maybe a small XML and the XSD.  I'm not sure, what's going wrong right now.  I never had any problems with the order of elements.  Attributes on the other hand are in arbitrary order, but these shouldn't have any influence on the validation.

Comment: Actually you're right. I misinterpreted the diff between original and modified XML. Thanks, I wouldn't have taken another look without your comment :)